# Android Air App Locks up due to RPCDataManager?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am currently developing an Android app using FlashBuilder 4.5 (AIR) annd I have almost finished it apart from a few things. One of these things is that during testing of the app I notice that an Error was happening to do with the RPCDataManager. I beleive this maybe to do with the NavigateToUrl functions I have in the App as this is when the eroor occurs. The two NavigateToUrl function in the app are below:

```
protected function link_icon_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest(getJByIDResult.lastResult.link));
                //tel, sms, mailto, market, http and https
            }

            protected function email_icon_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var urlString:String = "mailto:";
                urlString += "?subject=";
                urlString += getJByIDResult.lastResult.c_name+" Information";
                urlString += "&body=";
                urlString += getJByIDResult.lastResult.j_name+" "+getJByIDResult.lastResult.dl+" "+desc_txt.text+" "+getJByIDResult.lastResult.link;
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest(urlString));
            }
```

Now these Functions are initiated when the users cliks on either a Mail icon or a Internet icon. They Functions actually work and do redirect you to a Website and Send an E-mail, however no matter which one you select there seems to be an error triggered which then completley locks up the application and does not allow any further actions (Back, Home etc.). Ther error code thta is created is shown below:

```
Error: Requesting : cRPCDataManager:cRPCDataManager:#:1.website_link
    at mx.data::DataList/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::fetchItemProperty()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataList.as:3609]
    at mx.data::ConcreteDataService/fetchItemProperty()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\ConcreteDataService.as:2540]
    at mx.data.utils::Managed$/getProperty()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\utils\Managed.as:164]
    at valueObjects::_Super_Companies/get website_link()[C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Dropbox\Projects\GApp\GApp Final\src\valueObjects\_Super_C.as:132]
    at ObjectOutput/writeObject()
    at mx.data::DataList/writeExternal()
    at mx.data::DataList/writeExternal()[C:\depot\DataServices\branches\milestone\lcds45_fb45\frameworks\projects\data\src\mx\data\DataList.as:727]
    at mx.collections::ArrayCollection/writeExternal()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ArrayCollection.as:161]
    at ObjectOutput/writeObject()
    at spark.components.supportClasses::ViewDescriptor/writeExternal()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\ViewDescriptor.as:179]
    at ObjectOutput/writeObject()
    at spark.components.supportClasses::NavigationStack/writeExternal()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\NavigationStack.as:238]
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to help if you don't provide more code, but my guess is that you're trying to call something like "#:1.website_link" in your LCDS service.  I don't think this has anything to do with navigateToURL since it's specifying an LCDS class.